# SVG animation is too large: 3.5mb

Tags: animation, svg, filesize

I made an svg animation using inkscape and Shapeshifter.design. Each number here is its own path. It looks good but the resulting output is 3.5mb!! I've tried svg reduction websites but no luck. Is there a way to implement this that isn't so big? Raw svg is too big to upload here so i am [adding a link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=56125618753953141821) to a file

Comment: Your link to file doesn't work for me?

Comment: @TomWyllie Oops, fixed